# C# Regular Expression to match letters, numbers and underscore

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression pattern in C#. The pattern can only allow for:

- letters
- numbers
- underscores

So far I am having little luck (i'm not good at RegEx). Here is what I have tried thus far:

```
// Create the regular expression
string pattern = @"\w+_";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

// Compare a string against the regular expression
return regex.IsMatch(stringToTest);
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**EDIT :**

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+$"
```

or

```
@"^\w+$"
```

Comment: @JoeWhite the second match also the uppercase english letters http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cw%2b%24&i=ABC&o=m

Comment: The first solution only works for English letters and might fail for other alphabets.

Answer (score 32):

@"^\w+$"

\w matches any "word character", defined as digits, letters, and underscores. It's Unicode-aware so it'll match letters with umlauts and such (better than trying to roll your own character class like [A-Za-z0-9_] which would only match English letters).

The ^ at the beginning means "match the beginning of the string here", and the $ at the end means "match the end of the string here". Without those, e.g. if you just had @"\w+", then "@@Foo@@" would match, because it *contains* one or more word characters. With the ^ and $, then "@@Foo@@" would not match (which sounds like what you're looking for), because you don't have beginning-of-string followed by one-or-more-word-characters followed by end-of-string.

Answer (score 3):

Try experimenting with something like http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/ which lets you develop regex interactively.
It's designed for Perl, but helped me understand how a regex works in practice.

Answer (score -1):

Regex

```
packedasciiRegex = new Regex(@"^[!#$%&'()*+,-./:;?@[\]^_]*$");
```