# C# Regex to match letters, numbers, underscore, dash and point

Tags: c#, regex

I looking for this but i can't found a good solution.

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885860/c-sharp-regular-expression-to-match-letters-numbers-and-underscore) but visual studio get an error

```
var regexItem = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+$);
```

And it's my condition:

```
if (regexItem.IsMatch(name))
{
     //...
}
```

Comment: If i were a compiler i would complain about a missing closing quotation mark in `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+$`.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: with this `Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+$);` the range of string is peddling and other line of coed get syntax error like : `; expected`

Comment: Do you also want to match Unicode letters? Or just Latin script only? If you also want to add Unicode support, `@"^[\w.-]+$"` will suffice in C#.

Comment: if I post the above, some would come and tell that `\w` would match also some extra chars other than `A-Za-z0-9_` does. SO I always go with op's way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just include the pattern for dash and point inside the character class. And it's safe to put `-` at the last or at the first inside the character class.

```
new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$");
```

Comment: If we want the string don't have `.` (point) in start and end what's your solution?

Comment: `new Regex(@"^(?!\.)(?!.*\.$)[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$");`

Comment: And if we want `_` and `-` don't come immediately after or before `.` ?

Comment: you adding more and more conditions.

Comment: `new Regex(@"^(?!\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*[_-]\.)(?!.*\.[-_])[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$");`

Comment: then you need to give bounty for me.. :-)

Comment: Your solution works for me but indeed the '-' (dash) HAVE to be at the last positon. I just wanted to add ' _ ' (underscore) at the end but the '-' was no longer accepted. So, I just add the ' _ ' (underscore) before the '-' and it works. Do you know why ?