# How to convert alphanumeric value to int in c#

Tags: c#, sql, string, int

I have alphanumeric value = 106bd87f9386b63b. I want to convert this value into integer in c# and store the converted value into database. Is there any possibilities to convert it.

Comment: obviously "1 183 277 369 562 412 603"  is too big for int

Comment: long number = long.Parse("106bd87f9386b63b", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

Comment: If this is an encrypted block, as you've tagged, maybe you want to store this as a binary or varbinary column in your database instead?

Comment: I guess you'd need to know how the value was encoded. Perhaps it is hex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use this:

the strLong is a declared variable.
and see this for your reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
long.Parse(strLong, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with multiple methods choose one which is suitable to you 
**Method 1**:
If you want to do it with **Regex** Here is Example helpful in Detail

[C# Regular Expression to match letters, numbers and underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885860/c-sharp-regular-expression-to-match-letters-numbers-and-underscore)

 Here is also a useful and detailed link 
[Find and extract a number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string)

**Other Methods**:
You can also use `Char.IsNumber('your character here')` 
here is Doc link of Microsoft 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isnumber?view=netframework-4.7.2 
For the above method you have to split your string into characters and then check if it is character or not using `Char.isNumber()` Method .
Instead of all these you can also split this and make a function and match ASCII values and detect weather it is a number of not . 
What ever method you use just detect number or not and concatinate it into a string and then at the end convert this string into a number using Convert class provided by Microsoft . Here is the detailed link of conversion 
[How can I convert String to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)